# Copying files from docker volume to kubernetes volume

Tags: kubernetes-helm, docker-volume, persistent-volume-claims

I am moving my service to kubernetes from docker and I also have to copy over some files from my docker volume.

I am using a `PersistentVolumeClaim` and a `StorageClass` in kubernetes and that's already implemented.

But now I need to copy the contents in the folder `/opt/checker/dataFiles` to the same mount path on kubernetes. How best to do it ? Is there a better way than copying the files into the folder inside the kubernetes container manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I couldn't find any and I ended up doing this manually:

Copy the contents from the docker volume to you local disk (`docker cp container:source_path local_dest_path`)

Copy the contents into the Kubernetes volumes into the mount path (`kubectl cp local_dest_path namespace/pod:final_dest_path`)